# Как поменять разрешение экрана в Windows 10 QEMU?

Tags: linux, windows-10, экран, qemu

Запускаю виртуалку так:

```
 ~ $ qemu-system-x86_64 -smp cpus=8 -m 8G -k en -m 8G -hda ./windows.img -boot c -accel kvm -bios ./tianocore-uefi.fd -vga vmware
```

Разрешение экрана - 800х600, да его ещё нельзя поменять! Экспериментировал с -vga - результата никакого! Как поменять разрешение экрана на ноутбучное (если я не ошибаюсь, 1366*1024)

Comment: Как менять на нотебучное и вообще на любое другое не знаю. Но на полный экран я запускаю так
`qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -machine q35 -cpu host -device intel-iommu -cdrom /home/sergey/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.215.iso -drive file="win10.qcow2",if=virtio -m 8G -vga qxl -usb -device usb-tablet -display gtk,zoom-to-fit=on -full-screen`

Answer (score 1):

Поставь virtual-manager, прицепи образ диска и нет проблем с разрешением и проброс усб мышкой...

А под капотом тот же qemu, с такими параметрами

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -name guest=win7test,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-win7test/master-key.aes -machine pc-i440fx-2.8,accel=kvm,usb=off,vmport=off,dump-guest-core=off -cpu Haswell-noTSX-IBRS,md-clear=on,ssbd=on,spec-ctrl=on,hv_time,hv_relaxed,hv_vapic,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff -m 16000 -realtime mlock=off -smp 8,sockets=8,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid 924c5309-9aa9-48d9-8192-44818a256ff1 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=26,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=localtime,driftfix=slew -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay -no-hpet -no-shutdown -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 -boot strict=on -device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x7 -device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x5 -device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x1 -device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5.0x2 -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -drive file=/data/VM/win7.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0 -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=1 -drive if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-1,readonly=on -device ide-cd,bus=ide.0,unit=1,drive=drive-ide0-0-1,id=ide0-0-1 -netdev tap,fd=28,id=hostnet0 -device e1000,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:ac:e0:77,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev socket,id=charserial1,fd=29,server,nowait -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial1,id=serial1 -add-fd set=3,fd=31 -chardev file,id=charserial2,path=/dev/fdset/3,append=on -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial2,id=serial2 -chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel0,name=vdagent -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 -device usb-tablet,id=input0,bus=usb.0,port=1 -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,seamless-migration=on -device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vram64_size_mb=0,vgamem_mb=16,max_outputs=1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 -device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0,bus=usb.0,port=2 -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1,bus=usb.0,port=3 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
```

Касательно видео тут ключевое это выделение видеопамяти:

```
-spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,seamless-migration=on \
-device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vram64_size_mb=0,vgamem_mb=16,max_outputs=1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2
```

Картинку можно смотреть spice клиентом или можно заменить на vnc. А отрисовку напрямую в иксы опцией -vga не пробовал даже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это на базовом драйвере Microsoft. На драйвере Redhat изображение не мерцает при прокрутке. А если еще установить Windows guest tools - spice-guest-tools, то разрешение экрана подстраивается под размер окна в котором его смотрим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если работать в голом qemu, то тут нужно добавить ещё канал spicevmc

Comment: я с virt-manager вообще не разобрался, честно. А за команду под капотом спасибо, попробую...

Comment: не знаю, как это работает, но `qemu-system-x86_64 -k en -m 8G -smp cpus=8 -hda windows.img -boot c -accel kvm -bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd -net user` для меня сработал. Разрешение поменять нельзя, но хотя бы добился комфортного значения 1200*800

Comment: попробовал virt-manager... что-то ни намека на настройку разрешения экрана...

Comment: Он видюху qxl прокидывает. Разрешение ставится уже средствами виндовс

Comment: Возможно надо поставить дрова на неё

Comment: я вручную запустил с опцией `-vga virtio`. Поставил дрова, но системе все равно

Comment: @RandomDice779 обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить к команде

```
-full-screen
```

Comment: опасная опция. Просто потому что виртуалка выводится на весь экран и я не могу свернуть ее

Comment: да и экран отобразился криво

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал VNC (не разобрался со spice), поставил драйвера на spice в Windows, а толку - 0[image][image]